# Zend Framework form with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, validation, zend-framework, zend-form

Any one a idea how to simply create a form with Zend_Form and jquery? I want to use Zend_Form to validate the form so I don't have to dual script the form in JavaScript and PHP.

Thank you,

Ivo Trompert

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No problem there.

Add ZendX_JQuery to your library if you use autoload.

Then extend ZendX_JQuery_Form to your needs.
Do your stuff in the init() method of your class.

For example, I was able to create an AutoComplete field which has regular Zend_Form validation plus JQuery behavior like this:

```
$elem = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_AutoComplete(
    'query',
     array('Label' => 'Search',
           'required'=>true,
           'filters'=>array('StripTags'),
           'validators'=>array(
                            array('validator'=>'StringLength',
                                'options'=>array('min'=>'3'),
                                'breakChainOnFailure'=>true
                                ),
                            array('Alnum')
                )
        )
    );

$elem->setJQueryParams(array('data' => array(),
    'url' => 'my_autocomplete_callback.php',
    'minChars' => 1,
    'onChangeInterval' => 500,
    )
);
```

Then I even changed the default decorators like this:

```
$elementDecorators = array(
    array('UiWidgetElement', array('tag' => '')),
    array('Errors', array('tag' => 'div', 'class'=>'error')),
    array('Label'),
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div')),
);
$elem->setDecorators($elementDecorators);
```

And finally add to my form (remember I'm in the init() so I'll address it via $this):

```
$this->addElement($elem);
```

There you are, the magic is done.

PS: don't forget to add the following in your bootstrap:

```
$view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');
```

Comment: Please beware that - ZendX will be dropped and will no longer be supported.

Comment: @Jonathan http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Discontinuing-Maintenance-of-ZendX-JQuery-Suggest-drop-for-2-0-td3221856.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, Zend_Form will not generate any client-side JavaScript validators for you, if that's what you mean.

BUT: You can just do all the validation on the server, and use jQuery to hook into the fields' change events, and to AJAX-ify the form validation.

Check [that](http://www.whitewashing.de/blog/articles/92) for a sample.

Answer (score 0):

http://web.archive.org/web/20100814175334/http://steven.macintyre.name/zend-framework-jquery-form-validation-plugins/
Here we show how to add a plugin to the Zend framework to handle the client side vlidation