# formvalidation with php and javascript/jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, validation, forms

im new in formavalidation.

i am wondering if there is some library class you can download and include and then use for formvalidation in php and also in javascript/jquery?

it would save a lot of time so you dont have to reinvent the wheel.

thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What if you wanted to share validation rules between jQuery and PHP without "reinventing the wheel" or repeating your code?  That may have been the intent of the original question, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html) for form validation, but it does not integrate with jQuery AFAIK.

EDIT: the folllowing SO question may be what you are looking for : [Zend Framework form with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665690/zend-framework-form-with-jquery)